# How do you use Git? I would like to push a file back into the Github repo?

Tags: git, github, push

I am currently collaborating with a few others on a large Java project, and have cloned the repository to work on it from my home PC. I went ahead and changed 2 files within the whole directory/subdirectory structure of this gigantic project, and would like to just push those two files I've edited back into the repository.

Is there a command I can use in order to accomplish this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git pull origin master` - make sure your master branch is up to date with the latest changes in the remote repository defined by origin (frequently github).

`git status` - show files that you've modified in the branch you are in.

`git add` . - add the files you've modified to your current branch.

`git commit` - save changed files to your current branch.

`git push origin master` - send the changed files in the master branch to the remote repository.

Answer (score 2):

If you added new files make sure to add them with `git add`

`git commit -a -m "Commit message"`

`git push`

To get any new changes they made ahead of yours you'll need to pull first

`git pull`

then fix any merge conflicts and commit the merge.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you committed your change and it's in a branch that already exists on the server, you can simply use `git push`.

Answer (score 0):

Once you've `git clone`d the repository, and made changes to files, you can use `git status` to see what files have changed.

Select changes to commit using `git add`. When you've selected ('staged') all the changes you wish to commit, `git commit` them. That will commit to your local repository.

To push the commits to github, use `git push`.

If you're new to git, I'd *very* highly recommend you at least browse through the [Pro Git book](http://progit.org/book/). It's got some good diagrams and explanations for a whole bunch of git topics; I found it very useful. In particular, for this question, look at the ['Recording changes to the repository'](http://progit.org/book/ch2-2.html) and ['Working with remotes'](http://progit.org/book/ch2-5.html) sections.

The [StackOverflow Git FAQ / Wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/git/info) also has some neat information for common questions; some of those are related to yours, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315911/git-for-beginners-the-definitive-practical-guide#316055).

Edit: As an aside, about this part of your question:

> ... just push those two files I've edited...

Git thinks in terms of *commits*, not in terms of *files*. You can't push a subset of files in your repository, because a commit encompasses the entire repository at the time of the commit. `git push` and other network-type `git` commands, though, are pretty darn good at working out what they should be sending to the remote repositories. Don't worry, even if the repository is large, if you've changed two source files, a `git push` won't push every single file back to the remote repository.